# Why does text of the same size appear different in Photoshop than in Word?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Ok so here you can see text in MS Word. 11 pt Times New Roman looks way bigger than the text in Photoshop at the same size and in the same font. The resolution in Photoshop was and has always been 72 pixels/inch.

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/197/textsize.png/]

Comment: The size of the type in the word document is relative to the size of the document itself. Rarely are you working on a screen where the Word document is the exact size as the printed document.

Comment: Pixel Density: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13013/when-creating-pdf-from-file-what-determines-100-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching & a lot thinking, this is what i have come up with...i hope not to confuse even more...ppi(pixels/inch),72pt= 1in..ok...so i was wondering why is that whats 1 inch in Photoshop looks way bigger in word. it turns out what photoshop does is scale inch to match your monitor's resolution. So suppose your monitor resolution is 1000x1000 and you make an image with ppi of 50ppi and size of 500x500 pixels ..meaning 1 inch now would have 50 pixels in it.  So how many inches would be the picture...10 inches in both width and height. There are 50 px in 1in and there are total of 500. so 10in equals 500px (10x50=500). But here is the thing normal and unsuspecting people would think that 10 inches would be 10 in long and if you put ruler on your screen it would measure the widhth/height 10 inches right...and then you would be wrong...think about it just because you told photoshop to make your photo to be shown at higher density(ppi) how do you expect monitor to do that, it cant just produce more pixels in area of 1 in... so instead photoshop makes inches smaller and bigger...so when its high ppi which means higher density or more pixels per inch than monitor stretches 'inch' to do that. so if your resolution is 1200x900 and you make an image with ppi of 1200 than 1 inch in that file would be equal to the whole width of your monitor but the actual size that it would appear on screen would be the size in pixels...if its 500 pixels that image would be 500 pixels wide...
but font is however related to how big your image file thinks 1 inch is. and if there is a difference between ppi of your photoshop, web and word then font will appear different in each. I found out that my monitor's ppi is about 92 (1600pxResolution/widthofMonitorinInches) and i am setting photoshop to be 72px/in, i guess i should say 1/72 in/px...and 1/92 in/px so font appeared smaller because an inch in photoshop was 72 pixels and in my  monitor 92 pixels. Therefore i guess web and word doesnt care about custom ppi and now that i think about it you cant define what ppi your page should look like on internet.

Comment: Keep in mind that none of your software likely knows the PPI of your monitor. It can only guess.

Comment: There can be any number of "pixels in 1 inch". A **pixel has no size or measurement**. Photoshop has a "Screen Resolution" or pixel density setting in the preferences.

Comment: yes i understand that now....the thing is for people with normal mindset it'd slip that pixels are fixated and inches are somewhat negotiable..and font size is dependent on, in photoshop, the size inch in pixels...and if ppi of your document and screen are different things may look different. :D

Comment: yes..default ppi in photoshop was 72 and my monitors is like 92..

Answer (score 1):

Is your view zoomed in Word? Or have you changed the resolution settings in Photoshop?

Whenever anything looks wrong in a Microsoft app, I just assume they know better than all the other apps in the world ;)

Comment: no i checked it was 100% in both.

Comment: 100% in P'shop is actual pixels. In Word I believe it's attempting to approximate print size.

Comment: source it....let me see if google docs does it too.

Comment: ok i checked text against google docs and same thing, ps text is smaller. like half...resoultion  72 and zoomed 100%

Comment: Right. If you have a high resolution display, your 'actual pixels' or 100% setting in Pshop may very well be smaller than what Word/Docs thinks is print size.

Comment: i calculated my monitor's ppi and its 91.79 PPI.

Comment: Now the text in browser does it behave like photoshop or like word.

Comment: Photoshop. At 100%.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Grab a ruler and hold it up to your screen. Measure the the actual word document you have open and zoom in/out until it matches the paper size exactly. Rarely (if ever) does the '100%' zoom in Word match a real physical sheet of paper since the software has no clue as to the actual pixel density of the device it is displaying on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to take copy from Word and match the size in Photoshop
you can fix the problem by setting up your Photoshop resolution to 300 (standard print resolution).

Go to Photoshop preferences under the "Photoshop" in the top menu bar. Select Units and Rulers. You can Change your font measurement to Points instead of Pixels. Word uses points so this will help get the font size match you are looking for.

Word documents are typically print documents so I am presuming that it will have a 300ppi resolution. (I am no word expert just an educated guess)